# Implement interfaces for slices

Tags: go

Upon playing with Go, I came across the question: is it possible to implement an interface for slices? I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere. I tried the following without success:

```
type t1 struct {
    prop string
}

type i1 interface {
    toString() string
}

//ok
func (o t1) toString() {
    return o.prop
}

// ERROR invalid receiver []i1 (basic or unnamed type)compiler(InvalidRecv)
func (o []i1) toString() {
}

// ERROR invalid receiver []t1 (basic or unnamed type)compiler(InvalidRecv)
func (o []t1) toString() {
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to declare a method on a slice type? There are lots of examples, like https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP or https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage

Comment: Hi, @JimB, thank you for the references! My goal was to padronize implementations of interfaces for the sake of reusability. Although your references does solve the problems, it was not quite what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a method for a slice. You can define a new type from a slice, and define a method for that:

```
type t1Slice []t1

func (o t1Slice) toString() {
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var arr []t1
t1Slice(arr).toString()
```

Comment: Ha! That makes sense! It should be allowed to do this more explicitly though.

Comment: There is a reason for this. Methods can be defined for "named types". A slice type is not a named type until you name it by declaring a new type.